# How to merge a sequence of arrays in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, foldleft

I have a value of type `Seq[Array[Int]]` and I want to end up with a single `Array[Int]`.  I thought foldLeft would work, but surprisingly it doesn't:

```
scala> val arr1 = Array(1,2,3)
arr1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val arr2 = Array(4,5,6)
arr2: Array[Int] = Array(4, 5, 6)

scala> val seq = Seq( arr1, arr1 )
seq: Seq[Array[Int]] = List(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(1, 2, 3))

scala> seq.foldLeft ( Array.empty )( (x,y) => x ++ y )
<console>:17: error: value ++ is not a member of Array[Nothing]
       seq.foldLeft ( Array.empty )( (x,y) => x ++ y )
                                                ^
```

That error doesn't seem like the entire truth though because I can do this:

```
scala> Array.empty
res22: Array[Nothing] = Array()

scala> Array.empty ++ arr1 ++ arr2
res23: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `seq.flatten.toArray` ?

For `foldLeft` solution you should tell type to compiler: `Array.empty[Int]`, when you missed that `[Int]`, the compiler chose `Nothing` as the only possible type for `Array.empty`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm still getting familiar with scala's type inference.  But you're right, `seq.flatten.toArray` is nicer.